# Webserver not showing at host - Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I am unable to access the app outside the container, when I `exec` inside the container and do curl localhost:8000 it is showing but the same app is not reflecting in the host browser. Any help would be appreciated.
main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urlparse(self.path)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({
            'myfavourite author name': 'shakespear',
        }).encode())
        returnx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), RequestHandler)
    print('Starting server at http://localhost:8000')
    server.serve_forever()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest
COPY . ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python main.py
```

requirements.txt

```
urllib3
httpserver
```

Comment: Docker creates a network per container, see https://docs.docker.com/network/. You should listen at 0.0.0.0 and expose the port 8000 (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to 0.0.0.0 for your program to accept connections from outside the container. Like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), RequestHandler)
    print('Starting server at http://0.0.0.0:8000')
    server.serve_forever()
```